# "user operation is waiting for creating "maven-archetype-quickstart", eclipse unable to proceed further for creating Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-3

[image][! [enter image description here] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYTTa.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYTTa.png)

I am using the latest version of "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2022-12", but I am unable to create "Maven-Archetype-Quickstart" as it is stuck at 33% all the time.

I tried restarting Eclipse and the system as well.

Comment: Is there a `Confirm properties configuration` message in the console? If so it is waiting for you to type `Y` to confirm.